# Hide a form field with a specific id after submit

Tags: php

I'm new here and a super noob in programming. I'm having trouble with my project. My problem is that I'd like hide the form after submit and retain the data input in it.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$displayform = true;

if (isset($_POST['trck']))
{
    $track = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['tracknumber']));
    $ord = $_POST['id'];
    $displayform = false;

    if (!$track)
        echo "Please enter your tracking number!";
    else 
    {
        mysql_query("update `orderdetails` set `trackno`='$track' where `id`='$ord'");
    }

    if ($row2['id']==$ord)
        echo $_POST['tracknumber'];
    }

    if ($displayform)
    {
?>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="tracknumber" id="tracknumber" size="30" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter your track number here." />

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>">

        <input type="submit" name="trck" id="trck" value="Save" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to save this tracking number?\');" />
    </form>

    </td>
</tr>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

This code was inside a while loop and my problem with this is that after I submit all the form is hidden. All I want is to hide the form with the specific ID on a query.

Comment: Why dont you show us the full (formatted please) code including the CSS part where you hide the form. Also I noticed that the form doesnt have an id at all

Comment: In before `mysql_query()` deprecated blah blah blah...

Comment: @GillianLoWong - It's not a CSS that hides the form, but the `if($displayform)` that evaluates to false after the submit.

Comment: @BonCorcino, this code isn't even close to do what you want. I suggest you to study a little more about the basics of web development.

Comment: Where is the while loop? It helps to show that as well

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) hide

Include the jquery as

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){
  $("#formid").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this in your `<form>` tag:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="awesome_form" onSubmit="document.getElementById('awesome_form').style.display = 'none';">
```

Answer (score 0):

use the jQuery and use :

```
$("#submitButtonId").click(function(){
   $('#formId').hide();
});
```

or else in pure javascript use

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="hideIt()"/>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function hideIt() {
  document.getElementById('formId').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

its better not to use inline javascript